# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get_data'

Tags: python, recursion

I am having `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get_data'` this error while testing one of my functions. The test script works alright with the sumnc_rec() function but not on rest of them. I am sharing my functions below, any suggestion to solve this problem will be of great help, Thank you.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/CMPT 145/Assignment 7/a7q7_testing.py", line 38, in <module>
    output = a7q7.countnc_rec(chain, target)
  File "D:\CMPT 145\Assignment 7\a7q7.py", line 36, in countnc_rec
    elif chain.get_data() == target:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get_data'
```

Here's my code

```
import node as N

    def sumnc_rec(chain):
        if chain is None:
            return 0
        else:
            return chain.get_data() + sumnc_rec(chain.get_next())
    
    
    def membernc_rec(target, chain):
        if chain is None:
            return False
        elif chain.get_data() == target:
            return True
        else:
            return membernc_rec(chain.get_next(), target)
    
    
    def countnc_rec(target, chain):
        if chain is None:
            return 0
        elif chain.get_data() == target:
            return 1 + countnc_rec(target, chain.get_next())
        else:
            return countnc_rec(target, chain.get_next())
```

Here's the node class

```
class node(object):

    def __init__(self, data, next=None):
     
        self.__data = data
        self.__next = next


    def get_data(self):

        return self.__data


    def get_next(self):

        return self.__next


    def set_data(self, val):

        self.__data = val


    def set_next(self, val):

        self.__next = val
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: I have done so @quamrana

Comment: Where are you calling those functions - ```sumnc_rec``` ? Please post those statements as well. I think you are passing a ```int``` to this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show your calling code until after I asked for the full error traceback. I suspected what was going on because someone else posted a similar piece of code earlier today.

You should swap your parameters:

```py
output = a7q7.countnc_rec(target, chain)  # target first, then chain
```

Comment: Apologies for inadequate information, but swapping worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think chain is an integer variable, and it doesn't have the get_data() method, maybe try checking if that statement is right.

Comment: This should be a comment and not answer.